Getting a UniqueViolation error, but the apparently unique key doesn't appear to exist in the DB
I'm using Python to transfer CSV files with 100,000+ rows each into a database. I had it archive CSV files that were successful, leaving any problem CSVs behind. I'm not seeing any obvious differences in the problem CSV data compared to the archived CSV data. The archived data exists with queries in PgAdmin. The problem data does not exist using the same queries.
My troubleshooting output in Python is baffling:
query="select exists(select time from history_eurusd_part_table where time='2017-10-03 00:00:00.183000')"
result=False
query="insert into history_eurusd_part_table (time,ask,bid,ask_volume,bid_volume) values ('2017-10-03 00:00:00.183000',1.17321,1.17319,1310000,1000000)"
UniqueViolation: data="'2017-10-03 00:00:00.183000',1.17321,1.17319,1310000,1000000", e=UniqueViolation('duplicate key value violates unique constraint "history_eurusd_2017_pkey"\nDETAIL:  Key ("time")=(2017-10-03 00:00:00.183) already exists.\n')

time TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,
                ask DECIMAL(8, 5),
                bid DECIMAL(8,5),
                ask_volume INT,
                bid_volume INT

I check to see if a value already exists in the table.
If the select exists query runs successfully, I fetch the result.
If the result is false, I attempt to insert the problem data into the DB.
query = f"select exists(select {fieldnames[0]} from {tableVals['name']} where {fieldnames[0]}={row[0]})"
                    print(f"{query=}")
                    success = Attempt_Query(cur, query, [])
                    # If check if entry exists query executes successfully
                    if success:
                        result = cur.fetchone()[0]
                        print(f"{result=}")
                        # If entry doesn't exist in db, insert
                        if not result:
                            data = ",".join(row)
                            query = f"insert into {tableVals['name']} ({columns}) values ({data})"
                            print(f"{query=}")
                            # If insert fails, return false to avoid archiving
                            if not Attempt_Query(cur, query, data):
                                csvInDB = False

def Attempt_Query(cur, query, data):
    cur.execute(query)

Why does the select exists statement indicate that the data DOES NOT exist, and yet the insert statement insists that the data DOES exist?
I am able to add the data manually using a query in PgAdmin. Which makes me confused as to why the Python code worked for other files, but not the remaining ones.
Archived (Good) File:
time,ask,bid,ask_volume,bid_volume
2003-05-05 00:00:05.536000,1.12177,1.12161,35700001,14400000
2003-05-05 00:00:06.561000,1.12182,1.12166,600000,800000
2003-05-05 00:00:14.085000,1.12183,1.12163,60500000,800000
...

Remaining (Error) File:
time,ask,bid,ask_volume,bid_volume
2017-10-03 00:00:00.183000,1.17321,1.17319,1310000,1000000
2017-10-03 00:00:00.715000,1.17323,1.17318,3750000,3750000
2017-10-03 00:00:01.225000,1.17323,1.17318,3370000,3000000
...


Do you know what the SELECT EXISTS looks like? From this piece of code, we can't see what SQL statement is created; we have no idea. Besides that, this code is slow by design, every INSERT makes the next SELECT slower. I would use COPY to put all data in one go in a staging table, remove all duplicates from this staging table and use one INSERT to move the unique data to the target table. Most likely that will be about 100000 times faster.

select exists(select time from history_eurusd_part_table where time='2017-10-03 00:00:00.183000')
That's copied directly from the output in the first code snippet. The reason I didn't use copy was because the first row of the csv has fieldnames which throws an error. So I need to reformat all of the csvs. Which I can do, however, I'm trying to address the problem of the UniqueViolation which doesn't seem to make sense. Speed was not my issue. Does speed solve the UniqueViolation?

Just tell COPY that you have a header: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html or https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

If you want to use INSERT, you can drop the SELECT statement and use an ON CONFLICT handler in your INSERT. It is still much slower than using COPY, but it will be faster and doesn't have issues with conflicting keys

I had considered this, however, I want to verify that all of the data gets into the database. I'm suggesting the UniqueViolation isn't actually a UniqueViolation. The data isn't actually in the database, and yet it's throwing a UniqueViolation despite this. If I use the ON CONFLICT method, and it throws a UniqueViolation, it will move on without inserting... just like it does now.

I'm suggesting the UniqueViolation isn't actually a UniqueViolation. The database has a different opinion... This can only happen when your primary key index has been corrupted. It's unlikely, but it could happen. Use REINDEX to fix this.

Actually the database doesn't have a different opinion. I can successfully run the INSERT statement from pgadmin.

Is it possible that my Python code is running a concurrent query? Would that cause the UniqueViolation?


Do not use f strings when psycopg2 has a module sql that will build dynamic SQL in a safe manner. 2) What does Attempt_Query() do? Add as text update to question text.


Are you running multiple inserts within a single transaction and have you verified that the CSV doesn't have duplicate times? If a series of inserts are performed within a single transaction and there are duplicates within the set, then UniqueViolation will be raised and the entire transaction will be rolled back. If the reported duplicate didn't exist prior to starting the transaction, then it won't exist after the exception occurs.

How do you define transaction? I do have multiple inserts between opening and closing the connection and before committing.

If you've turned of psycopg2's autocommit mode, then all of the statements prior to a COMMIT or ROLLBACK are in a single transaction. A new transaction starts when the next statement other than COMMIT or ROLLBACK is executed. Unfortunately, there not enough context in the post to determine your execution environment.

I was able to make it work, albeit extremely slowly, by wrapping every insert with a new connection and commit. So the UniqueViolation definitely seems to be related to the number of queries per transaction. I attempted to switch to Copy, wound up updating Python and switching from psycopg2 to psycopg3 along the way... finding it very difficult to make it work. There doesn't seem to be as many examples/tutorials using psycopg3 and psycopg2.


What is the point of Attempt_Query(cur, query, data) if you don't actually use the data? 2) Solve one problem at a time, switching methods and software is the definition of flailing.


I created Attempt_Query initially to narrow down the error, which led me to discover that catching the exception changes the error.
